# Unresolved Identifier JSON with SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I tried researching my issue but it is tough to find info about it. I am working with Alamofire and SwiftyJSON in a project and Alamofire is working but the SwiftyJSON is not working.

I did the install "manually" as seen in the documentation here [SwiftyJSON git repo](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) and dragged the SwiftyJSON.swift file into my project. I have also verified it is part of the compiler sources under the project settings. Here is my code that I am using. It should work fine but i keep getting an ' "unresolved identifier 'JSON' ' error.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let route = "myurl"
    let params = myparams
    Alamofire.request(.GET, route, parameters: params).responseJSON { (_, response, rawJSON, _) -> Void in
        let json = JSON(rawJSON!)
    }
}
```

I was doing this in the prepare for segue (which may be a bad idea) but my biggest issue is that it doesn't realize that the SwiftyJSON is in my project. If anyone has any ideas for fixing this/ places to point me it would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view controller file needs to belong to all of the targets that `SwiftyJSON.swift` is a member of.

You probably included `SwiftyJSON.swift` in your test target but not your view controller.

To fix this:

1. click `SwiftyJSON.swift`
2. press **View** -> **Utilities** -> **Show File Inspector**, and
3. uncheck the test target.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Cocoapods, you might have to add the library to the 'link binary with libraries' and import it to the class where you use it